# a "... doesn't match its definition" problem, that I don't understand

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I managed to extract from my code the following MnWE which shows the problem i encounter :

**Example 1**

```
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\createDATA}[1]{
  \xdef\DATA{}
  \newcommand{\test}[2][]{
    \xdef\DATA{\DATA args=##1 , ##2 }
  }
  \test[x]{\macom[x]{blabla}}
}
\newcommand{\macom}[2][q]{AAA}
\createDATA
\DATA
\end{document}
```

The compilation gives an error : `! Use of \\test doesn't match its definition.` which I can't understand. 
On the other hand, notice that if in the definition of `\createDATA` I replace `\macom` by a command without optional argument, then it works :

**Example 2**

```
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\createDATA}[1]{
  \xdef\DATA{}
  \newcommand{\test}[2][]{
    \xdef\DATA{\DATA args=##1 , ##2 }
  }
  \test[x]{\macomm{blabla}}
}
\newcommand{\macomm}[1]{BBB}
\createDATA
\DATA
\end{document}
```

It is very mysterious to me...

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. But the problem is using a command with optional argument inside an `\xdef`. The error message is not quite informative, however.

Comment: This is the problem with minimal examples ... they sometimes have not meaning. This one just illustrates a problem, that i encounter in my code (which has a meaning!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to `\edef` (`\xdef` = `\global\edef`) the macro `\macom`. However, as `\macom` is a command with an optional argument, this cannot be done safely. You need to either not do an `\edef`, use the LaTeX protected mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createDATA}[1]{%
  \xdef\DATA{}%
  \newcommand{\test}[2][]{%
    \protected@xdef\DATA{\DATA args=##1 , ##2 }%
  }%
  \test[x]{\macom[x]{blabla}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\macom}[2][q]{AAA}
\createDATA
\DATA
\end{document}
```

or make `\macrom` engine robust using the e-TeX extensions, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\createDATA}[1]{%
  \xdef\DATA{}%
  \newcommand{\test}[2][]{%
    \xdef\DATA{\DATA args=##1 , ##2 }%
  }%
  \test[x]{\macom[x]{blabla}}%
}
\newrobustcmd{\macom}[2][q]{AAA}
\createDATA
\DATA
\end{document}
```

(By the way, you have a lot of extraneous spaces in your commands: I've added `%` to kill line ends and deal with these.)

For more on what robust, protected and 'fragile' means, see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

---

The reason that you cannot `\edef` a command with optional arguments is that these are picked up using the TeX primitive `\futurelet`. This performs an assignment, and assignments are not expandable. On the other hand, grabbing a mandatory argument does not require any tricks, so it is expandable.

[It's a bit more complex than that, as there are ways of expandably testing for optional arguments. These are more restrictive than the non-expandable approach, and the LaTeX2e kernel therefore goes with comprehensive-but-non-expandable. For pre-constructed methods for both expandable and non-expandable optional argument grabbing, with automatically robust functions and lots of additional cleverness, see the LaTeX3 [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) module.]

Comment: As egreg has commented on the question, I have no idea why there is an `\edef` being used here, hence saying that one (perhaps the most obvious) option is to simply avoid it entirely.

Comment: Could you please explain why one can not safely `\edef` a command with optional argument, but can do it without optional argument.

Comment: @nicolasroy No optional argument is a necessary condition for a macro to be safe in an `\edef`. Not sufficient. To be safe it must expand to unexpandable tokens without any intervening assignment. It's also important to note that the expansions are "all the way down".

Comment: See also [Why isn't everything expandable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35039/why-isnt-everything-expandable) and [Why isn't a command defined by \newcommand with an optional argument expandable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/why-isnt-a-command-defined-by-newcommand-with-an-optional-argument-expandable).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. Nevertheless, I don't understand your solution 1 : i thought that `\protected@xdef` would have a special effect (preventing expansion) on macro which are preceded by `\protected` in the `edef`, or defined with `\protected`. Did i miss something ?

Comment: @nicolasroy `\protected@edef` prevents issues here as the LaTeX kernel defines `\macom` to automatically engage LaTeX protection internally. It's not quite the same as the effect if you use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define `\macom`, which 'automagically' adds `\protect`. However, these still rely on the way `\protected@edef` works. On the other hand, anything defined using e-TeX's `\protected` primitive is immune from expansion inside any form of `\edef`-like context. The way `\protected@edef` works would be worth a separate question.

Comment: is there a similar issue with environment with optional arguments ? Is there an equivalent of `\newrobustcmd`  for environments ?

Comment: @nicolasroy Exactly the same ideas apply. An environment `foo` is based on a macro `\foo` and potentially `\endfoo`. I'd simply use `\renewrobustcmd\foo` after defining the environment, or use `xparse` where there is a proper interface for this.