# Is it possible to define a command taking an optional star and working in a subscript?

Tags: macros, subscripts, starred-version

*Note*: this is more or less a cross-post from my blog.  I hope this is acceptable, especially that this is a genuine question!

I’m currently writing a (longish) document on mathematics. Among other things, I write about the Hausdorff metric, which I denote by `$d_H$`. Since this notation appears quite often, I decided to write a command for it:

```
\newcommand{\dH}{{d_H}}
```

The additional braces are there, because sometimes I want to talk about a ball with respect to the Hausdorff metric, denoted by `$B_{d_H}$` – for that, I wanted to write `B_\dH`. Without the extra braces this won’t work (for obvious reasons).

So far, so good. But there’s another catch: I want a similar notion to the Hausdorff metric (call it a Haudorff quasimetric), which I denote by `$d_H^*$`. With my definition, `\dH^*` won’t work (I want the star to be above the subscript). So I wanted to be clever, and use an optional star; this way, I could write `\dH` or `\dH*`. I did this:

```
\newcommand{\dH}{\@ifstar{d_H^*}{d_H}}
```

But my ability to write `B_\dH` is lost now! And of course, adding braces around `\@ifstar` won’t help: it will then never “see” the star.  (Note: I know that `xparse` makes defining commands with optional stars easier, but I expect it won't help with my problem.)

Personally, I can see no way out of this dilemma. It’s not a big deal, I can write `B_{\dH}` (which is cleaner LaTeX syntax anyway), but I’m curious whether there’s any way to eat this cake and have it, too.

Comment: I think it is better to accept to always use `B_{\dH}`, as promoting `B_\dH` to ends up being weird as it depends on the definition of `\dH`. I might even consider using `\BdH` as a shortcut for that ball

Comment: Agreed (I more or less stated it in the question anyway), but my curiosity is still unsatisfied...

Comment: I'm guessing you will need some of the hardcore `expl3` people to explain how this can be done with `xparse`, using `{d_H}` in an `\NewDocumentCommand`, then `B_\dH` does not work at all.

Comment: Might even be better to make a more intelligent ball macro instead with a syntax like `\Ball[type=H](0,1)`

Comment: Same issue happens with optional argument, because that one expands to `\@ifnextchar`. Or [`\NewDocumentCommand`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512119/missing-inserted-error-when-using-newdocumentcommand-command-as-a-subscrip).

Comment: Remark: The solution has some [spacing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437378/250119) with things that does not expand to a `mathord` though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Delay the closing of the group: after `_`, one can use `\bgroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dH{\bgroup d_H\@ifstar{^*\egroup}{\egroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$B_\dH$ and $B_\dH*$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But avoid it.

Comment: +1 even though unbalanced groups always hurt my brain. Does one need to use `\bgroup...\egroup` here or would `\begingroup...\endgroup` also be possible?

Comment: This. Is. Pure. Awesome.  (Though an extremely dirty trick.)  The only reason I didn't accept this (yet?) is that I want to wait for more answers (though it seems unlikely that they'll come...)  May I submit this to the "TeX beauties and oddities" session for the next BachoTeX conference (with due credit, of course?)

Comment: @mbork Of course you can. `;-)` Note that `\bgroup...\egroup` don't hurt when `\dH` is used at the normal level, because the symbol is ordinary anyway.

Comment: One question: why define `\s@dH`?

Comment: @mbork Possibly not needed, actually. Removed.