# Why do some commands require explicit braces in subscripts?

Tags: implicit-braces

Most single commands don't require explicit braces if they appear in a subscript or superscript.  For example,

```
a_\text{n}
```

compiles fine.  But a few do require explicit braces: for example,

```
a_{\tilde{n}}
```

compiles while

```
a_\tilde{n}
```

does not.  Is there any rule for which commands must be surrounded by explicit braces in a subscript even when they appear by themselves?

Comment: The `\text` macro happens to be defined in a particularly clever way. As a side-effect, as you've discovered, it can appear without curly braces as the argument of a `_` subscript initiator. For most other macros, it's necessary to help TeX parse the material correctly by enclosing the macro *and* the argument(s) in a pair of curly braces.

Comment: in addition to what Mico says, unless the sub/superscript is a single letter or digit, it's never a bad idea to enclose it in braces.

Comment: Related question on the topic of super/subscript and braces: [macros - Is it possible to define a command taking an optional star and working in a subscript? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195445/is-it-possible-to-define-a-command-taking-an-optional-star-and-working-in-a-subs)

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

> Always use braces. Always use braces. Always use braces.

## Some more words

The LaTeX manual always uses

```
_{<subscript>}
```

even if the subscript consists of a single token and it has very good reasons for doing so; for instance, it would propose

```
a_{1}+b_{11}
```

Experienced users tend to omit the braces, but this can be very dangerous. For example, the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$A_\in+A_\notin$
\end{document}
```

will fail with

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \mathrel 
l.3 $A_\in+A_\notin
                   $
```

because `\notin` is not really a single object.

An input such as `A_\tilde{x}` will similarly fail. On the other hand,

```
F_\mathrm{eff}
```

will work, but it's just luck. So, what's the rule?

Sorry, there's none except ***always*** using braces.