# Underbrace in equation environment error

Tags: equations, underbrace

Code:

```
%\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{bm}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{equation}{14}
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{d}{dt}\left(\mathcal{H}_u\right) = 0 = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial t} + \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^{\textrm{T}}\underbrace{\dot{\mathbf{x}}}_{\mathcal{H}_\bm{\lambda}} + \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial \bm{\lambda}}\right)^{\textrm{T}}\dot{\bm{\lambda}} + \cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial u}}\dot{u}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

While the code above looks correct, here is the output:

[image]

While the braces are correctly placed, the output comes out incorrect; instead of `\mathcal{H}_\bm{\lambda}` only being placed in the `underbrace` (I only want `\mathcal{H}_\bm{\lambda}` to be under the `underbrace`), the latter half of the expression gets written under the `underbrace`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, define incorrect for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\mathcal{H}_\bm{\lambda}` needs to go to `\mathcal{H}_{\bm{\lambda}}` as in (I skipped some of the packages)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{14}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\diff}{\diff t}\left(\mathcal{H}_u\right) = 0 = 
    \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial t} + 
    \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^{\textrm{T}}
    \underbrace{\dot{\mathbf{x}}}_{\mathcal{H}_{\bm{\lambda}}}
    + \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial
    \bm{\lambda}}\right)^{\textrm{T}}\dot{\bm{\lambda}}
     + \cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}_u}{\partial u}}\dot{u}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure if the underbace is pretty, but there is no error.

Comment: Hmmmmm this is interesting. I wonder why there needs to be a brace surrounding the subscript...

Comment: Also, kind of off topic, but is the `\diff` command more commonly used than just a plain `d` in derivative?

Comment: @Superman Because otherwise you get an error. ;-) In more detail, this has to do with how `\bm` is defined (vs. `\mathrm`, say). And yes, differential `d`s are to be typeset upright and `\diff` takes care of the spacing in many standard situations. Why upright? `Let $d$ be a distance, then its time derivative, $\drac{dd}{dt}$ ????`. Math operators are upright, which is why you get upright symbols with `\DeclareMathOperator`. I know someone on the faculty in the computer science department somewhere will object, but this is a standard convention among many/most.)

Comment: Standard convention in pure and applied math and sciences?

Comment: @Superman There are different opinions but the above argument: `Let $d$ be a distance, then its time derivative, $\drac{dd}{dt}$ ???` should be enough. Also a d-dimensional integral `\int d^dx`? `\frac{\diff d}{\diff t}` and `\int \diff^dx` with the above upright `\diff` are unambiguous. I follow the conventions used by most people I know who thought about this, including Ed Witten, a top-level physicist who also won the Fields medal.

Comment: @Superman --- Take a look at this: [Why do some commands require explicit braces in subscripts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297838)