# LaTeX Beamer - Make text in math mode also serif

Tags: beamer, fonts, sans-serif

I am using a sans-serif font for my beamer slides but the regular serif math font for my equations. However, if I use `\text{}` in math mode, the sans-serif font is used. I would like to enforce that the serif font is used when using `\text{}`.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I would like to make $f_\text{LO}$ look like $f_\mathrm{LO}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Replace sans-serif font in math mode with serif font]

**Update:** I found out that I should not redefine `\text{}` but use `\textrm{}` instead to use the serif font in math mode. By doing that, I can still add regular text using `\text{}`.

Comment: \text is as the names says for text, for math use \mathrm (or define a some meaningful wrapper command). And use braces around the subscript: `f_{\mathrm{LO}}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342272/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. The problem with `\mathrm{}` is that I manually have to add spaces and it behaves differently for hyphens. However, `\textrm{}` works fine

Comment: ? There are no spaces in your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I only realized that when I replaced `\text{}` with `\mathrm{}` in my document where I use spaces and hyphens. Thank you anyway!