# Reasons not to use \newcommand{{...}} (with double curly braces)

Tags: macros, best-practices

Which are the reasons *not* to always use `\newcommand{\stuffa}{{STUFF}}` instead of `\newcommand{\stuffb}{STUFF}`? In which cases would the former be a bad idea?

The reason I am considering doing this is to make the commands work e.g. in superscripts without extra curly braces, i.e., `2^\stuffa` works while `2^\stuffb` doesn't (`2^{\stuffb}` does). These commands will not only be used in superscripts, though, and I'm interested in a more general answer anyway. (If e.g. `xparse` provides a convenient solution to this problem, that would be interesting as well.)

I assume that this is a very basic question that has been answered many times, but I could not find an answer with a reasonable amount of research.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195445/64293) is related but does not answer my question.

Comment: Also note that if it takes optional argument, it won't work in (right after a) superscript anyway. See linked question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195447/250119

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The definitions are completely different, only add the extra group *if you want an extra group*

```
\newcommand\zzz{\bfseries}
```

would make `\zzz` an alias for `\bfseries` and `\zzz this`  would make a bold **this**

```
    \newcommand\zzz{{\bfseries}}
```

would do nothing useful as the font change would be in a group that ends immediately.

```
\newcommand\recip{\frac{1}}
```

would define a reciprocal function `\recip{4}` would typeset 1/4.

```
\newcommand\recip{{\frac{1}}}
```

would do nothing useful as `\recip{4}` would be `{\frac{1}}{4}` and raise an error about a missing argument for `\frac`.

The fact that having the extra group in the definition makes `x^\stuff` seem to work is an accident of the implementation and should not be used. The documented LaTeX syntax is always to brace superscripts.

In general it will change the spacing,

```
\newcommand\zzz{+}
```

will make `\zzz` act like +

```
\newcommand\zzzb{{+}}
```

will make `\zzzb` act like `{+}` which isn't usually wanted, and gets no space compare

```
 $1  \zzz 2  \zzzb 3$
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful and answers my question. I do have to say that I find it a pity that the use of the braces cannot be avoided - longer math equations are already difficult to parse, and putting extra braces everywhere doesn't improve readability (in my opinion).

Comment: @jhin in the end it is much easier for computers and humans to parse `x^{frac{1}{2}}y` than `x^\frac12y` where knowing where the superscript ends requires knowing an awful lot of context.

Comment: @campa my definitions do what I claim but I didn't write what I intended, sorry:-) fixed..

Comment: "The documented LaTeX syntax is always to brace superscripts": if I recall correctly, Knuth's own TeXbook says that braces are optional around single tokens.

Comment: @GregMartin Knuth's texbook does not document LaTeX, Lamport's LaTeX book does. And as shown in the example in the question the "optional for single tokens" applies to _macro arguments_ not to superscripts. The braces are not optional here, which is the reason for the question.