# NewDocumentCommand with embellishments does not work in superscript/subscript without braces

Tags: xparse

The following example

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\K}{e{^}}{{\exp(\IfValueT{#1}{#1}n)}}

\begin{document}
These work \( \K, 2^{\K^{2}}, 2_{\K}, 2^{\K}, \log(\K)\).

These do not \( 2_\K , 2^\K \).
\end{document}
```

Shows cases in which my command with embellishments (I am using TeXLive 2020). Is this expected? How do I fix the command definition so that all examples work?

Comment: Sub- and superscripts should _always_ be given in braces

Comment: I understand that's the preferred method of doing things and I tend to follow that style. But clearly examples like `2^\K` and `2_\K` work when `\def\K{K}` for example. The inconsistency is what is problematic to me.

Comment: I don't really see the inconsistency: even the TeX book states clearly that omitting the braces is fine only for a single character. Note that `2^\K` fails also for `\def\K{KK}`. And having after `_` or `^` a macro taking an argument has (almost) never worked.

Comment: @campa. `2^\K` would work as expected for `\def\K{{KK}}`.

Comment: Yes, clearly. That's why I've added an "almost" `:-)`. It's the kind of dirty coincidence why something like `x_\mathrm{...}` also works.

Comment: @Tohiko That's the 'relying on expansion behaviour' business: you need to know that `\K` expands such that the first non-expandable token is `{_1`. You can't do that in general terms. (With hindsight, it would have been better if `\mathrm` for example didn't do that, so people learned to properly brace their input.)

Comment: The underlying reason why some works and others don't are explained in [macros - Is it possible to define a command taking an optional star and working in a subscript? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195445/is-it-possible-to-define-a-command-taking-an-optional-star-and-working-in-a-subs) and linked questions ; nevertheless you need deep understanding of how TeX works at low level to understand the answers.

Comment: @JosephWright, point taken. Thanks for explaining. I agree that the `\mathrm` example shouldn't have worked in the first place. I deal with collaborators who use my commands in the "natural way" and it's difficult to explain to them that there's nothing wrong with my command when other commands like `\mathrm` work as "expected".

Comment: @Tohiko Try with the simple example `$X_\notin$`. The idea of adding braces to the definition of `\notin` wouldn't work, because the symbol would lose its status as relation symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sub- and superscripts should *always* be given in braces. TeX's rules for handling `_` and `^` if followed by non-braced material depend on the expansion behaviour of the tokens. This is problematic as

- The expansion behaviour is not always obvious
- The rule is different from argument grabbing
- The outcome can be different if `_` or `^` are active tokens rather than
  using TeX's catcode approach

In contrast, `_{...}`/`^{...}` *always* work *the same way*: this is the *only* supported syntax in LaTeX.