# Why do optional arguments of commands affect spacing of \mathcolor

Tags: macros, spacing, color, optional-arguments

I am very surprised that simply adding an optional argument to the definition of my command changes the spacing in formulas in combination with `\mathcolor`. Why does this happen? How can this be fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
\newcommand{\optionalSub}[2][a]{_{#2}}

\newcommand{\noOptionalSub}[1]{_{#1}}

%other example:
\newcommand{\coloredSubscript}[2][red]{_{\mathcolor{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

%MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
$a^b\optionalSub{c}$ %correct spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\optionalSub{c}$ % very wrong spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\noOptionalSub{c}$ %correct spacing

%other example:
$a^b\coloredSubscript{c}$ %correct spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\coloredSubscript{c}$ %very wrong spacing

\end{document}
```

[image]

To summarize: `\mathcolor` alone does not influence the spacing (which I appreciate a lot) and adding optional arguments usually also does not change the spacing (as I appreciate a lot). But somehow using both of them directly next to each other changes the spacing? Why?

Comment: mathcolor has to look ahead to see a following `_` or `^` which has to be there via expansion, the lookahead and test for optional argument stops that so \mathcolor does not see the `_`

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50784/250119 . But have you considered using like `\mathcolor{blue}{a}^{\mathcolor{blue}{b}}\coloredSubscript`? (tl;dr: What you want isn't **supported** by `\mathcolor`, which requires an explicit `^` or `_` after it to work. Use something else.)

Comment: @user202729 it doesn't have to be explicit, just reachable by expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` that doesn't suffer from the problem of the check for the optional argument in the legacy `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\optionalSub}{O{a}m}{_{#2}}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\noOptionalSub}{m}{_{#1}}

%other example:
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\coloredSubscript}{O{red}m}{_{\mathcolor{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

%MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
$a^b\optionalSub{c}$ %correct spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\optionalSub{c}$ % very wrong spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\noOptionalSub{c}$ %correct spacing

%other example:
$a^b\coloredSubscript{c}$ %correct spacing
$\mathcolor{blue}{a^b}\coloredSubscript{c}$ %very wrong spacing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The similar problem is in OpTeX, but not with regards to the next parameter given by an un-expandable macro. Simply

```
$ {\Blue a^b}_c $
```

gives c after `a^b` (i.e. with space, wrong position) because the `{...}` is interpreted not only as a begin/end group but also as a new atom in math list. We have to replace `{` and `}` by `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`. These TeX primitives only open/close group but they don't construct math atoms. The solution is:

```
\def\mathcolor#1{\begingroup#1\endgroup}

$\mathcolor{\Blue a^b}_c$
```

Note that we don't need to do nothing more (no checking of following `_` like in LaTeX), because OpTeX sets colors using LuaTeX attributes.

Comment: Yes, if you are LuaTeX-only life is easier ...